# Iterating through HtmlNodes that has been converted to a list

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

After some searching I came to a solution to modify `HtmlNodes` (Html Agility Pack) while iterating through them. In this example a  tag will be added as a parent to each  tag. I am using the following code (c#):

```
foreach(HtmlNode currentNode in descendants.ToList())
{
   if (workingnode.name == "strong"){
       HtmlNode theParent = workingNode.ParentNode;
       HtmlNode newElement = workingDocument.CreateElement("a");
       newElement.SetAttributeValue("href", "Glossary.xhtml#gloss");
       newElement.AppendChild(workingNode);
       theParent.ReplaceChild(newElement, workingNode);
   }

}
```

What are the disadvantages of using the `ToList()` method on my descendants before iterating through them? I'm just concerned that if it was this easy to do, it would be the first suggestion to most of `HtmlNode` modification questions.

Comment: Unless you know ahead of time exactly what you're looking to modify or remove (and can create a more narrow selector based on those criteria), a loop is the most efficient way. It's unclear what you're asking for, specifically.

Comment: I have made my example a bit more specific. So for each strong tag a link will be added to a glossay page.

Comment: @Morne I don't see anything wrong with this approach as long as it doesn't cause noticeable impact. And what is the most suggested approach in `HtmlNode` modification questions so far? Any link to those questions? just curious..

Answer (score 1):

The `ToList` method will iterate through a collection and add each item to a generic `List`. If your `descendants` variable is an `IEnumerable<T>`, or other collection type, then there is no point in calling `ToList` on it as the `foreach` loop can accept an `IEnumerable<T>` input as standard. Therefore, if that is true, then the following line would be more efficient as it wouldn't have to iterate through the collection to create another collection:

```
for (int i = descendants.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // Modify the document by adding a parent or removing this node.
}
```

Comment: This will does work as the following exception is thrown: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. The

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead like my [edited] example... thinking more about it, you might need to make it run backwards if you are going to delete any elements... I'll update it again... done.

Comment: Note that this is not any faster performance-wise because `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` iterates through the collection in order to obtain a count, so in this example you are effectively iterating the collection twice. You should use a `foreach`, unless you are making changes to the collection itself, in which case you can make a `List` of items to remove or change, and then make the change in a secondary loop.

Comment: @SpikeX, it was a `foreach` loop previously, but the question author wanted to make changes to the items, so I changed it... good point though. +1